# shell_exec not working when calling node

Tags: php

Im trying to execute the node command from PHP with this function:

```
$output = shell_exec('node -v');
echo $output; // null
```

and it returns me null instead of version. Why it's not working? Node.js is installed on the server and working when executing from shell.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the shell_exec function says

> This function can return NULL both when an error occurs or the program produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the program exit code is required.

Its possible that `node -v` dosn't output to stdout or that another error is occurring. Could you maybe try another program such as `uptime`, its also worth noting it won't work if your PHP is running in `safe_mode`.